# iOS In-House Distribution Error 'Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=109'

Tags: ios, https, plist, manifest, in-house-distribution

I am trying to distribute an iOS 7.1 app using In-House distribution on an Enterprise Account. Currently I have a web page that has a link that should install my app. The code for the link is below.

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.my-website.com/app/app.plist" id="text">Install App! </a>
```

I have my .html file, .plist file and .ipa file all on a https website. However, I still get the useless error "Cannot connect to www.my-website.com" when I click on the link. Viewing the console logs shows the following error.

Warning: Could not load download manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=109 
"Cannot connect to www.my-website.com" UserInfo=0x14e27630 
{NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to www.my-website.com, SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=404}

I looked all over the web for this error but none were of code 109. And 404 was not helpful since it just meant the page was not found.

NOTE: I am using IIS for my website.

Comment: If you use IIS have you authorize to download plist and ipa fileExtension in your web.config ?

Comment: Hi Maathusan , I have a doubt belongs to plist .Can we able to view plist file in browser after setting MIME of plist ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that because I was uploading the 3 files (.html file, .plist file and .ipa file) using IIS, I needed to add the unrecognized MIME types for the .plist and .ipa extensions.

Therefore, I needed to add `text/xml .plist` and `application/octet-stream .ipa` into IIS Manager. This can easily be done with the help of this link:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx

NOTE: If you're using Apache you will need to create a .htaccess file will the following

```
AddType text/xml .plist 
AddType application/octet-stream .ipa
```

Big thanks to the following post for helping me resolve this issue: http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/install-air-apps-on-ios-devices-over-wifi

Comment: Hi Rajendram , i am facing same issue . I added these types to my IIS ,but still i am getting same error .Can you help me out ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey, do you still need help? I can try my best to help you, if you specify what you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks Maathusan ,now my issue has been cleared .My Manager added MIME types in IIS server .So now we can able to download the iPa file directly .